# PHP MSSQL Pagination doesn't go to the next page

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>  
</head>  
<body>  

<?php  
$sql_name = 'test';
$sql_user = 'sa';
$sql_pass = '';

$dbConn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server={$sql_name};",$sql_user,$sql_pass) or die('Database Connection Error!');

if (!$dbConn) {
    exit("Connection failed:".odbc_errormsg());
}

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM test_db.dbo.test ORDER BY ID ASC ";  
$objExec = odbc_exec($dbConn, $strSQL) or die ("Error Execute [".$strSQL."]");  
$Num_Rows = 0;  
while(odbc_fetch_row($objExec))$Num_Rows++; // Count Record  
  
$Per_Page = 22;   // Per Page  
  
{  
$Page=1;  
}  
$Prev_Page = $Page-1;  
$Next_Page = $Page+1;  
$Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page)+1;  
if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)  
{  
$Num_Pages =1;  
}  
else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)  
{  
$Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;  
}  
else  
{  
$Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;  
$Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;  
}  
$Page_End = $Per_Page * $Page;  
if($Page_End > $Num_Rows)  
{  
$Page_End = $Num_Rows;  
}  
?>  
  
<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">ID </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>  
</tr>  
<?php  
for($i=$Page_Start;$i<=$Page_End;$i++)  
{  
$objResult = odbc_fetch_array($objExec,$i);  
?>  
<tr>  
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["ID"];?></div></td>  
<td><?=$objResult["Name"];?></td>  
</tr>  
<?php 
}  
?>  
</table>  
  
<br>  
Total <?php echo $Num_Rows;?> Record : <?php echo $Num_Pages;?> Page :  
<?php
if($Prev_Page)  
{  
echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'><< Back</a> ";  
}  
  
for($i=1; $i<=$Num_Pages; $i++){  
if($i != $Page)  
{  
echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i'>$i</a> ]";  
}  
else  
{  
echo "<b> $i </b>";  
}  
}  
if($Page!=$Num_Pages)  
{  
echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>Next>></a> ";  
}  
  
odbc_close($dbConn);  
?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

When I press the button to go to the next page or any other page number it stays on the same page but if I change $Page=2; It will go to page 2 and when pressed to go to another page, it will stay at the same page.

Comment: looks like you are initializing the page with 1, but not with the Page value in query string?

Comment: It is much easier to make two queries, one to get just the total number of records, the other with the queried results for that page using SQL limit offset "OFFSET 44 ROWS FETCH NEXT 22 ROWS ONLY;" 44 being $Per_Page * ($Page - 1)